# Invoking TypeScript compiler as NPM module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, requirejs

I have a project written in TypeScript and I use a task runner for building (whatever: Gulp, Jake, etc.).
The TypeScript compiler i use is the one I installed from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript):

```
npm install typescript
```

**Important:** As you can see there is no global `-g` parameter and this is on purpose. As I need to use a specific version of the compiler with some modifications.

#### Calling `tsc` programmatically

So I want to invoke the compiler from my Javascript file configuring my task manager:

```
var tsc = require("typescript");

function compile() {
  tsc.compile(...); // I would like to do something like this
}
```

Can I do that? I have tried, but not getting much luck so far.

Comment: Have a look at [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript)

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6387#issuecomment-169739615) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 6):

You sure can. There are numerous tools - [`tsify`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify), [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node), [`ts-loader`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) - that are built using the [TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API).

However, it's a little bit more complicated than a single `compile` call.